# Change the background of the button that is used as a TabItem Header

Tags: c#, wpf

I using code from a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jma5VYwEQcY) to develop a GUI with Tab Menu in WPF. Here, the buttons act as the Tab Menu header and every button is linked with an id. Based on the user selection, the id changes which in turn triggers what is displayed when a particular button is clicked. I want to change the background of the button, if it is selected. How can this be done?

Following is the `xaml` code:

```
<StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <Grid Height="40">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20 0">
            <ComboBox FontSize="15" Width="50" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="EN"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20 0">
            <Button Content="FAQ" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="CONTACT" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="ORDER STATUS" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="MY ACCOUNT" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="100">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10 0">
            <Button x:Name="b1" Uid="0" Width="150" Content="HOME" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Uid="1" Width="150" Content="SHOP" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Uid="2" Width="150" Content="BLOG" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Uid="3" Width="150" Content="PAGES" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Uid="4" Width="150" Content="PRODUCTS" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Uid="5" Width="150" Content="BRANDS" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Uid="6" Width="150" Content="GIFT CARDS" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF2196F3" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="GridCursor" Width="150" Height="5" Background="#FF2196F3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 0"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="GridMain" Height="460" Background="Aquamarine">

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Following is the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = int.Parse(((Button)e.Source).Uid);

        GridCursor.Margin = new Thickness(10 + (150 * index), 0, 0, 0);


        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;
                b1.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
                break;
            case 1:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.Beige;
                break;
            case 2:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.CadetBlue;
                break;
            case 3:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.DarkBlue;
                break;
            case 4:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.Firebrick;
                break;
            case 5:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.Gainsboro;
                break;
            case 6:
                GridMain.Background = Brushes.HotPink;
                break;
        }
    }
```

I am able to change the background if the button is selected using `b1.Background = Brushes.Yellow;` . However, the background doesn't change to default when a different button is selected. Also, I am not able to set the background of the button (`Uid =1`) with which the GUI is launched.

Comment: I could suggest a completely different way of doing this. Hard coding a list of buttons is not how an experienced wpf developer would usually approach this sort of requirement.

Comment: @ Andy. I am new to wpf. Please suggest your approach.

Comment: It'd be more like a total rewrite, templating out ui from viewmodels. There are a number of options including actually using a tabcontrol rather than something looks a bit like a tabcontrol.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237958/dynamically-changing-tabitem-via-button-command-not-working-wfp/75238853#75238853

Comment: WPF has a thing called a selector which tabcontrol, listbox, listview and datagrid inherit from. When you click one of the items you select it. You can then use that with datatriggers to change the look of a selected item.  What look like buttons in this are not, the parent control on the left is a listbox with bound itemssource and templated items.  https://i.imgur.com/73rJR4i.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the community toolkit mvvm for this sample below. I'm not sure this does exactly what you're asking but the binding and templating demonstrates the mvvm approach.

My mainwindow - no buttons.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}"
                 x:Name="lb"
                 >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="160">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger
                                            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                                    Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                                    Path=IsSelected}"
                                                    Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   />
                        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                                CornerRadius="10"
                                >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackgroundBrushName}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding SelectedItem.BackgroundBrushName, ElementName=lb}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Mainwindowviewmodel

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public List<Choice> Choices { get; set; } = new List<Choice>
    {
        new Choice{ Description = "Shop", BackgroundBrushName = "Red"},
        new Choice{ Description = "Blog", BackgroundBrushName = "Blue"},
        new Choice{ Description = "Products", BackgroundBrushName = "Green"}
    };
}
```

Choice

```
public partial class Choice : ObservableObject
{
    public string BackgroundBrushName { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string description = string.Empty; 
}
```

None of those properties change but you should always implement inotifypropertychanged on any viewmodel and ObservableObject adds that.  description does not change so it doesn't really need change notification but I thought it would be interesting to see the code generator creates a Description property for you.

The collection is templated out into UI. The "menu" is a horizontal listbox which has the selector behaviour so you can click one and it is selected.

The background for the selected choice is usually visibility collapsed but a datatrigger sets it to visible if it's in the selected item.

We could also bind selecteditem mode=twoway and set that to the first choice if we wanted an initial one....errm... chosen.

Hopefully this gives you a reasonably beginner friendly introduction to mvvm techniques.

[image]